# get client id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer

I would like to know in which class and function can I get my client ID, the same bank saved ID as `entity_id`

I would like to `echo` my script so that I can manipulate it for other functions later.

This ID is from the connected client.

[image]

[image]

Magento 2.3.3
windows xampp
composer installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class Client
{

```
protected $customerSession;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    array $data = []
) {

    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}
public function getID(){
    return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

}

Resolved that way,
echo $this->test->getID();